# Return response of GET request from c++ to QML string

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I'm trying to do a simple GET request (with modified User-Agent), return response to QML and do a JSON parsing.

Actually it only returns page content when loading is complete but it doesn't return it to QML.

Sorry for the noob question. I'm new to this language and I'm trying to learn it :)

Here's my code:

**Home.qml**

```
function getRequest() {

[...]
console.log('Request...')
var jsonResult = JSON.parse(connectNet.connectUrl("http://myURL.com/index.php").toString())

lbOutput.text = jsonResult.predictions[0].description.toString()
    }
}
```

**connectnet.cpp**

```
#include "connectnet.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include <QDebug>
#include <QNetworkRequest>
#include <QNetworkReply>
#include <QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QUrl>


connectNet::connectNet(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
}

void connectNet::connectUrl(QString url)
{    
    QNetworkAccessManager *manager = new QNetworkAccessManager();
    QNetworkRequest request;
    QNetworkReply *reply = NULL;

    request.setUrl(QUrl(url));
    request.setRawHeader( "User-Agent" , "FAKE USER AGENT HERE" );

    reply = manager->get(request);
    connect(manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this,
                     SLOT(replyFinished(QNetworkReply*)));
}    

QString connectNet::replyFinished(QNetworkReply *reply)
{
   return reply->readAll();
}
```

**appname.cpp**

```
#ifdef QT_QML_DEBUG
#include <QtQuick>

#endif

#include <sailfishapp.h>
#include "connectnet.h"


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //INIT SETTINGS

    QGuiApplication *app = SailfishApp::application(argc, argv);
    QQuickView *view = SailfishApp::createView();
    connectNet ConnectNet;
    view->rootContext()->setContextProperty("connectNet", &ConnectNet);
    view->setSource(SailfishApp::pathTo("qml/APPNAME.qml"));
    view->showFullScreen();
    app->exec();
}
```

Hope I've well explained what I'm looking for. Thanks for your help.

## ====================================================

**EDIT 20/08/2015: added updated connectnet.h**

```
    #ifndef CONNECTNET_H
    #define CONNECTNET_H

    #include <QObject>
    #include <QNetworkReply>
    #include <QDebug>
    #include <QNetworkRequest>
    #include <QNetworkReply>
    #include <QNetworkAccessManager>
    #include <QUrl>

class ConnectNet : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    QNetworkAccessManager m_manager;
public:
  ConnectNet(QObject * parent = 0) : QObject(parent) {
      connect(&m_manager, &QNetworkAccessManager::finished,
      [this](QNetworkReply * reply) {
        if (reply->error() == QNetworkReply::NoError)
          emit replyAvailable(QString::fromUtf8(reply->readAll()));
      });

   }
signals:
    void replyAvailable(const QString & reply);
public slots:
    void sendRequest(const QString url) {
        QNetworkRequest request;
        request.setUrl(QUrl(url));
        request.setRawHeader("User-Agent", "MyLittleAgent");
        m_manager.get(request);
    }
};

    #endif // CONNECTNET_H
```

**this part of code gives a lot of errors :( (screenshot below)**

```
      connect(&m_manager, &QNetworkAccessManager::finished,
      [this](QNetworkReply * reply) {
        if (reply->error() == QNetworkReply::NoError)
          emit replyAvailable(QString::fromUtf8(reply->readAll()));
      });
```

compiling erros: https://i.stack.imgur.com/30vWn.jpg

Comment: your `ConnectNet::connectUrl(QString url)` returns nothing (void). what is that you parsing in `JSON.parse`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is that you think synchronously. The `connectUrl` cannot return a value (and it doesn't), since when it runs the result is not available. What you must do, instead, is for the `ConnectNet` class to emit a signal when the data is available.

It'd be a horrible idea if you tried to make a synchronous wrapper that did return the value: the QML engine would be stuck as long as it took for the result to be received. You could freeze your application by pulling the network cable at the right moment, or if the server was down. Users hate that, and it's a horrible antipattern that must be expediently eliminated and discouraged.

Here's how your `ConnectNet` (please, not `connectNet`, lowercase names are for members!) class could look. Note that the `QNetworkAccessManager` instance doesn't need to be a pointer.

```
class ConnectNet : public QObject {
  Q_OBJECT
  QNetworkAccessManager m_manager;
public:
  ConnectNet(QObject * parent = 0) : QObject(parent) {
    connect(&m_manager, &QNetworkAccessManager::finished, 
    [this](QNetworkReply * reply) {
      if (reply->error() == QNetworkReply::NoError) 
        emit replyAvailable(QString::fromUtf8(reply->readAll()));
    });
  }
  Q_SLOT void sendRequest(const QString & url) {
    auto request = QNetworkRequest(QUrl(url));
    request.setRawHeader("User-Agent", "MyLittleAgent");
    m_manager.get(request);
  }
  Q_SIGNAL void replyAvailable(const QString & reply);
};
```

Since `connectNet` instance instance is exposed as a property in the global QML context, you can connect to its signals as follows:

```
function getRequest() {
  connectNet.sendRequest("http://myURL.com/index.php")
}

function resultHandler(result) {
  var jsonResult = JSON.parse(result.toString())
  lbOutput.text = jsonResult.predictions[0].description.toString()
}

Rectangle { // or any other item
  Component.onCompleted: {
    connectNet.replyAvailable.connect(resultHandler)
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but I don't understand how to handle this SIGNAL in QML. How can QML know when data are available (signal emitted)? Could you show me an example code? Thanks :) P.S. Sorry but I'm really new to this language and a lot of things still appear confused.

Comment: @Simon it's via the [`connect`] call you see at the end of the code Kuba provided. See [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-signals.html#connecting-signals-to-methods-and-signals) for further details. Basically you are chaining the signal emitted with the corresponding signal handler (`resultHandler`). Another approach is the usage of the [`Connections`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-signals.html#using-the-connections-type) type.

Comment: @Simon It's C++11 code. Add `CONFIG += c++11` to your project file. Side note: It's 2015, if you're not writing c++11, you're making yourself work much harder than you need to. I'd call the pre-c++11 C++ experience to be outright miserable, in fact.

Comment: IT WORKS PERFECTLY! you're amazing! Thanks a lot!